# Show only first apperance of a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I have the following HTML structure, here class `post-4837` and `post-4836` are repeating. I have to show only the first one and hide the repeating ones:

```
<li class="product">
 <div class="some-other-class-names   post-4837">....</div>
</li>

<li class="product">
 <div class="some-other-class-names   post-4837">....</div>
</li>

<li class="product">
 <div class="some-other-class-names   post-4836">....</div>
</li>

<li class="product">
 <div class="some-other-class-names   post-4836">....</div>
</li>
<li class="product">
 <div class="some-other-class-names   post-4836">....</div>
</li>
```

How can I hide the duplicate product class using CSS or jQuery?

Actually, I want to hide all `.product` class whose `post-*` is repeated. The classes are generated dynamically, so I can't select using `.post-4836` and `.post-4837`. I want to select like `.post-*`.

Comment: @Durga it may seems a duplicate but it's not in this case ... we can do nothing with CSS here

Comment: you can only use JS/jQuery here

Comment: could you please any jquery solution

Comment: @TemaniAfif As OP knows the class name, and he stated in title *using css*, Thats why marked as duplicate.

Comment: @Durga but it's not a duplicate, there is a difference between both question

Comment: Of course it's not, but for some it is...

Comment: If you want a jquery solution, then what have you tried so far?  [ask]   And are you able to change how it's rendered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select them using `$("[class*='post-']")`. Then you'll have to iterate through them, get the number from the class, and check if you already have it in list. If you already have it, hide it. Otherwise, add it to the list.

```js
var groups = [];

$("[class*='post-']").each(function() {
  var c = this.className.substring(this.className.indexOf("post-") + 5);

  if (groups.indexOf(c) > -1)
    $(this).parent().hide();
  else
    groups.push(c);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="product">
  <div class="some-other-class-names post-4837">..1..</div>
</li>

<li class="product">
  <div class="some-other-class-names post-4837">..2..</div>
</li>

<li class="product">
  <div class="some-other-class-names post-4836">..a..</div>
</li>

<li class="product">
  <div class="some-other-class-names post-4836">..b..</div>
</li>
<li class="product">
  <div class="some-other-class-names post-4836">..c..</div>
</li>
```

Note: This assumes that the `post-*` class is always the last one in the `class` attribute. If that's not guaranteed, you'll have to change the line:

```
var c = this.className.substring(this.className.indexOf("post-") + 5);
```

To something like:

```
var c = this.className.match(/post-\d+/)[0];
c = c.substring(c.indexOf("post-") + 5);
```

Comment: Really thank you for athe answer and comment . But here  id is dynamic .

Comment: @abilasher You should've mentioned that in the question. I will update my answer.

Comment: also i need to hide .product class not .post-*

Comment: You also should've mentioned that in the question. See my updated answer.

Comment: @TemaniAfif That was not part of the question. Now that it is, I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Since the element with the class `post-XXX` are nested and **not sibling** there is no way to do with CSS. Here is a JQuery solution where I loop through all the product and use an array to store the ID's and I remove the duplicate one (if they already exist in the array):

```js
//empty array
var id=[];

$('.product > div').each(function() {
  //get all the classes
  var classes=$(this).attr('class').split(/\s+/);
  //loop all the classes
  for(var j=0;j<classes.length;j++) {
    //if the class match post-XXX
    if(classes[j].match(/post-(\d+)/)) {
      //get the ID
      var i=classes[j].split('-')[1];
      //test if ID exist
      if(id.indexOf(i)==-1) {
        //add it to array
        id.push(i);
      } else {
        //remove parent element (product)
        $(this).parent().hide();
      }
      break;
    }  
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="product">
 <div class="some-other-class-names   post-4837">A1</div>
</li>

<li class="product">
 <div class="some-other-class-names   post-4837">A2</div>
</li>

<li class="product">
 <div class="some-other-class-names   post-4836">B1</div>
</li>

<li class="product">
 <div class="some-other-class-names   post-4836">B2</div>
</li>
<li class="product">
 <div class="some-other-class-names   post-4836">B3</div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop inside the `ul` and get last `class` split and push a unique number in array.After that hide all which is not `eq` to 0. Working demo on snippet.

```js
var arrId = [];
$('ul li div').each(function(index, element) {
  var getclass = $(this).attr('class').split(' ').pop().split('-')[1];
  var stats = $.inArray(getclass, arrId);
  if (stats == -1) {
    arrId.push(getclass);
  }
});
$(arrId).each(function(index, element) {
var cls='div.post-' + element;
$(cls).not(':eq(0)').hide();
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="product">
    <div class="some-other-class-names   post-4837">....0</div>
  </li>

  <li class="product">
    <div class="some-other-class-names   post-4837">....1</div>
  </li>

  <li class="product">
    <div class="some-other-class-names   post-4836">....2</div>
  </li>

  <li class="product">
    <div class="some-other-class-names   post-4836">....3</div>
  </li>
  <li class="product">
    <div class="some-other-class-names   post-4836">....4</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using :first-of-type

```
.post-4837{
   display: none;
}

.post-4837:first-of-type {
   display: block;
}
```

OR

```
.post-4837 + .post-4837 {
   display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the *jQuery's* `first()` *method*:

```js
$(".product:has(.post-4837)").first().css('display','block');
$(".product:has(.post-4836)").first().css('display','block');
```

```css
.product {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li class="product">
  <div class="some-other-class-names   post-4837">..1st 4837..</div>
</li>
<li class="product">
  <div class="some-other-class-names   post-4837">....</div>
</li>
<li class="product">
  <div class="some-other-class-names   post-4836">..1st 4836..</div>
</li>
<li class="product">
  <div class="some-other-class-names   post-4836">....</div>
</li>
<li class="product">
  <div class="some-other-class-names   post-4836">....</div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a pure vanilla solution without using `post-[number]`
I gather all the classes, then I filter with 'post-', then I display only the first of type.

```js
var allClasses = [];

var allElements = document.querySelectorAll("*");

for (var i = 0; i < allElements.length; i++) {
  var classes = allElements[i].className.toString().split(/\s+/);
  for (var j = 0; j < classes.length; j++) {
    var cls = classes[j];
    if (cls && allClasses.indexOf(cls) === -1)
      allClasses.push(cls);
  }
}
allClasses.forEach(function(el) {
  if (el.substring(0, 5) == "post-") {
    console.log(document.getElementsByClassName(el)[0]);
    document.getElementsByClassName(el)[0].parentNode.style.display = 'block';
  }
});
```

```css
.product {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="product">
  <div class="some-other-class-names   post-4837">post-4837  1</div>
</li>

<li class="product">
  <div class="some-other-class-names   post-4837">post-4837  2</div>
</li>

<li class="product">
  <div class="some-other-class-names   post-4836"> post-4836  1</div>
</li>

<li class="product">
  <div class="some-other-class-names   post-4836">post-4836  2</div>
</li>
<li class="product">
  <div class="some-other-class-names   post-4836">post-4836  3</div>
</li>
```